# Serial vs concurrent blocking main queue in similar fashion

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

As I understand it, a concurrent queue runs operations concurrently, which is why they are used with barrier to solve read-write problems. However, I am not able to understand if a concurrent queue is called from main queue synchronously. It blocks the main queue for the time the read operation is getting performed. So, In such case concurrent queue behaved as a serial queue.

For example:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue_label", attributes: .concurrent) // concurrent queue
        
for i in 1..<11 {
    queue.sync {
        
        printNumber(from: i*10, to: (i*10) + 9)
    }
}
```

This gives the same result if a serial queue was used instead.

Because of this result, it make me confused about using serial queue or concurrent queue to solve read-write problem.

So my question is, why it is advised to use concurrent queue over serial queue to solve read-write problems?

The question is related to the use case of reading a stored property using a serial queue or using a concurrent queue.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev Sorry if the question was not clear. I Updated the question. Please help me to understand to make a wise choice between Serial and Concurrent Queues.

Comment: `sync` is `sync`. It doesn't matter what kind of queue you call, you are deliberately blocking yourself. If you are the main thread you block the main thread. The end. Hard to see what the question can be.

Comment: Your example is repeatedly calling `sync` from the same, single thread. So, of course it’s going to behave serially, because for each iteration of the loop, `sync` effectively says “wait for the queue to run this block before proceeding to the next iteration of the loop.” That results in serial behavior. But that doesn’t mean the queue is serial, just your use of it is. Regarding why people recommend “concurrent queue over serial queue to solve read-write problems”, is precisely to allow _multiple_ threads to perform reads concurrently, while still protecting writes with a barrier.

Comment: FWIW, I do not understand why this was closed. It seems perfectly clear to me and does not require more details.

Comment: By the way, while the concurrent queue approach (a reader-writer implementation) seems like it should be very performant, in practice, I have yet to find a use-case where `NSLock` implementation wasn't faster, and unfair locks even more so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue_label", attributes: .concurrent) // concurrent queue
```

If this queue has multiple items queued, then it *may* use multiple threads to run them in parallel. It does not promise that it will, but it may. And it will only do so if it has multiple items queued at the same time.

```
for i in 1..<11 {
    queue.sync { ... }
}
```

This loop queues a single item, blocks until the item is scheduled and completed, and then queues another item. If this is all the code, then at no point are there multiple items on the queue. Of course if there is other code running in parallel, that enqueues items on `queue`, then there may be parallel items running.

As written, this code is legal, but seems pretty useless. If `printNumber` is time consuming, and this is on the main queue, it could crash the app (or at least beachball it on Mac).

Nothing you've done here is a "read-write" problem, so I don't think that's related. Queues can be used to do all kinds of things. In this particular example, there doesn't seem to be any reason to use the queue at all, so I would delete that code. If you have a different problem, you can open a question asking about that.